# Force start and end date on an AmStockChart

Tags: amcharts

I'm building a AmStockChart with annual data. The problem is that I'd like to have a X axis going from 1/1 to 12/31 and currently the upper boundary is dynamically set with the  max date I have in the dataset.

Is it possible to force this? It seems that it can be modified within StockGraph.valueAxis but The documentation isn't really clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to archive this you need to add a "dump" entry in your [dataProvider](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmChart#dataProvider)

```
dataProvider = [{
    date: new Date(2014,0,1)
},
...
{
    date: new Date(2014,11,31)
}]
```

Comment: I figured that out after a while. Thanks anyway :)